# RestEasy ExceptionMapper not catching the exceptions

Tags: exception, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm throwing an exception `MyCustomException` from my application. (EJB Layer)

I've an exception mapper in web service layer which looks like following -

```
package net.webservices;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; 
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider; 
import net.common.MyCustomException;

@Provider 
public class EJBExceptionMapper implements 
ExceptionMapper<net.common.MyCustomException>  {

  public Response toResponse(MyCustomException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();    
}   

  }
```

I've registered my mapper in `web.xml` of the web service layer as following -

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>net.webservices.EJBExceptionMapper</param-value>        
</context-param>
```

The `EJBExceptionMapper` is not catching the `MyCustomException`. But instead its being caught by the catch block of the web service implementation.

What could be the problem?

Note: I don't want to register my ExceptionMapper manually using `getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper()`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your solution doesn't work (but I've never used RESTeasy, only Jersey). In any case, it would probably be simpler to extend `WebApplicationException`. That way, you don't have to register a provider:

```
public class MyCustomException extends WebApplicationException {
    public MyCustomException() {
        super(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw exception (of type MyCustomException ) in the catch block and add a "Throws MyCustomException" to the method signature